# Выделение диапазона между выбранными точками

Tags: python, matplotlib

есть точечный график в матплотлибе, необходимо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на две точки выделялся весь диапазон точек между ними ,не могли бы вы подсказать как это сделать ?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.text import Text
from matplotlib.image import AxesImage
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand
import matplotlib.backend_bases

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('click on points', picker=True)
ax.set_ylabel('ylabel', picker=True, bbox=dict(facecolor='red'))
line, = ax.plot(rand(100), 'o', picker=5)

selected_point = None  # создадим переменную для выделенных точек


def onpick1(event):
global selected_point
if isinstance(event.artist, Line2D):
    thisline = event.artist
    xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
    ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
    ind = event.ind
    print('X=' + str(np.take(xdata, ind)[0]))  # Print X point
    print('Y=' + str(np.take(ydata, ind)[0]))  # Print Y point

    

    # выделим новую точку
    selected_point, = plt.plot(np.take(xdata, ind)[0], np.take(ydata, ind)[0], 'ro')
    plt.draw()

    def onMouseClick(event: matplotlib.backend_bases.MouseEvent) -> None:

        axes = event.inaxes
        print(axes)
        # Если кликнули вне какого-либо графика, то не будем ничего делать
        if axes is None:
            return

        global marker
        if event.button == 3:
            marker.remove()
            

           

            # Координаты клика в системе координат осей
        xq = event.xdata
        yq = event.ydata
        text = f'({xq:.3f}; {yq:.3f})'
        print(text)

        
        marker = axes.text(xq, yq, text)
        if event.button == 3:
            marker.remove()
        axes.figure.canvas.draw()

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onMouseClick)


    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick1)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: @Глеб Не совсем понимаю каким образом произвести автоматическое выделение диапазона между двумя выбранными точками

Comment: При запуске вашего кода выдается ошибка `NameError: name 'event' is not defined`. Исправьте, пожалуйста.